# Spring Batch - how to access ExecutionContext from ItemListenerSupport

Tags: java, spring-batch

I'm extending `ItemListenerSupport` to trap errors encountered during read/process/write steps, like this snippet.

```
   @Override
    public void onWriteError(Exception ex, List<? extends BaseDomainDataObject> items) {
        logger.error("Encountered error on write", ex);

        String msgBody = ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex);
        numProcessedMap.computeIfAbsent("numErrors", val -> items.size());
        errorMap.put(numErrors.addAndGet(1), msgBody);
    }
```

How do I get all the errors I accumulated in the map into the `ExecutionContext` for the step or job (preferably)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do that is to create `StepExecutionListener` and inject `StepExecutionContext` into your custom `ItemListenerSupport` in `StepExecution#beforeStep()`.
The same for `JobExecutionContext` using `JobExecutionContext#beforeJob()`.

Or. more easly, let your custom `ItemListenerSupport` implements `StepExecutionListener` or `JobExectutionListener`